# selecting more fields causes catastrophic failure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, linked-server

I have a connection to a linked server from sql server 2012 to pervasive sql.

When I do `select field1, field2, field3 from mytable` everything works!

However, when I do `select field1, field2, field3, field4, ...field10+ from mytable` I get this erro message:

```
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "KSLAP208" reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "KSLAP208".
```

I looked at the logs and this is what it says:

```
2013-02-08 11:27:30.93 spid55      ***Stack Dump being sent to D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0049.txt
2013-02-08 11:27:30.93 spid55      SqlDumpExceptionHandler: Process 55 generated fatal exception c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. SQL Server is terminating this process.
2013-02-08 11:27:30.93 spid55      * *******************************************************************************
2013-02-08 11:27:30.93 spid55      *
2013-02-08 11:27:30.93 spid55      * BEGIN STACK DUMP:
2013-02-08 11:27:30.93 spid55      *   02/08/13 11:27:30 spid 55
2013-02-08 11:27:30.93 spid55      *
2013-02-08 11:27:30.93 spid55      *
2013-02-08 11:27:30.93 spid55      *   Exception Address = 00000000018F5BBE Module(UNKNOWN+0000000000000000)
2013-02-08 11:27:30.93 spid55      *   Exception Code    = c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
2013-02-08 11:27:30.93 spid55      *   Access Violation occurred reading address 0000000009400090
2013-02-08 11:27:30.93 spid55      * Input Buffer 128 bytes -
2013-02-08 11:27:30.93 spid55      *             select * from [KSLAP208].[C003]..PA_Profile_BASE_1119
```

I am able to do this same exact `select *` from a different server without problems!

What's happening here? Is this some kind of 2012 bug or a memory issue?

Comment: what happens when you select field1, field2, field3, field4, ...field10+ from mytable from another table?
You said select * works, but is everything you do from the other server exactly the same with different results?

Comment: amanda thank you for your comment. no i am unable to select more than some number of columns from another table. select* works from a different server, and any number of fields works from a different server, but not this one

Comment: let me clarify. i have sql 2005 and sql 2012, they are both linking to this one server. the 2005 is able to do any select, the 2012 is not

Comment: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14779212/251174). Do you have anything in the event log that can help you? What about anything in the logs of the server hosting your Pervasive instance?

Comment: So have you checked that Stack Dump file? That should help guide you to what actually crashed.

Comment: @swasheck: isn't it actually a duplicate question? A bit more than just related, I'd say at first glance.

Comment: what patch level for 2005 are you on?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      9.00.5000.00
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      2005.090.5000.00
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      2000.086.3959.00 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710)
Microsoft MSXML      2.6 3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      7.0.5730.13
Microsoft .NET Framework      2.0.50727.3620
Operating System      5.2.3790

Comment: @Marian I was giving the benefit of the doubt. Many times people get the answer and then change the question and are told to ask a new question

Comment: That's ***SSMS*** 2005. I don't see where you say something about the server version. What does `SELECT @@VERSION` give you?

Comment: @swasheck Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5057.00 (Intel X86)   Mar 25 2011 13:50:04   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

Comment: If you need to look at the stack or dump this'll get you started. http://mssqlwiki.com/tag/exception-code-c0000005-exception_access_violation/

Comment: @sql_handle thanks so much, can u tell me how i can use that to help me"? i am intimidated by it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are using Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC (MSDASQL) which is presumably pointing to the ODBC DSN for your Pervasive data source. Since the error is an Access Violation (AV), I'm willing to bet that the AV is raised due to something going wrong in the Pervasive ODBC driver. Since you also mention that this query works from some other machine, can you double check the:

1. ODBC DSN configuration between the 'bad' machine and the 'good' machine?
2. The ODBC driver version for Pervasive - is it the same on both 'good' and 'bad' machines?